# When using docker containers, is a docker hub account necessary?

Tags: docker

You do not have to have a Github account in order to create and maintain a git repository (but you do miss out on the benefits that Github uniquely offers).

In a similar vein, can you run your own Docker compatible container registry and repository?

I'm having a hard time finding reputable documentation that either describes how to host our own repo or alternatively states that with 100% certainty that you absolutely, positively must have a Docker Hub account and you have to store your containers with them if you want to use Docker tools. (Our intent is to create our own private containers.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When using docker containers, is a docker hub account necessary?

No, not necessary at all.

> can you run your own Docker compatible container registry and
>   repository?

[Absolutely](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-registry).

You can host your own, or you can use another vendor (like [AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)) to host private registries on your behalf.

Comment: This is the only answer needed for this question. :)